# How to drag drop columns in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

```
  I am working on telerik radgrid and radtree.
```

I want to drag from radtree and drop it on radgrid
for create column dynamically.
Also want to delete column by drag from radgrid and drop it on radtree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string type list in code behind for drag drop columns.
When drag a string add it into list and then bind the radgrid from that list.